# Topological term under electron-electron interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, topological-insulators

By integrating out fermions in gapped Dirac Hamiltonian, one can obtain a topological term for topological insulator. Why there is no further correction to this term when electron-electron interaction is included?

Comment: The coefficient of these terms must be quantized(usually by gauge invariance). So imagine there is some correction from electron-electron interaction, as long as the gap is maintained, the coefficient must change continuously, so it just stays the same unless a phase transition takes place.

Comment: @Meng Cheng Thanks! I know this argument. But is there any proof or explanation from Feynmann diagram point of view?

Comment: For the case of Hall conductivity, you can prove that diagrammatically using Ward identity. Let me see whether I can find a reference....

Comment: @Meng Cheng Thanks for providing me the clue, Meng. I think I have found one myself. [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/055032138790160X). They do apply Ward Identity which is valid under electron-electron interaction. But I am still little confused in their way of calculating current-current correlation function. It seems like they 'dress' both vertices. As far as I know, the Kubo formula in the interaction case only dress one vertex. But maybe that is an unrelated problem.